# Phoenix status_message_from_template/1 is undefined

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix 1.3, have normal `error_view` that was generated by phoenix.

```
...
def template_not_found(template, _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{detail: Phoenix.Controller.status_message_from_template(template)}}
  end
```

And error whenever someone hits wrong url in production:

```
 ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Phoenix.Controller.status_message_from_template/1 is undefined or private
        (phoenix) Phoenix.Controller.status_message_from_template("404.json")
        (hub) lib/hub_web/views/error_view.ex:14: HubWeb.ErrorView.template_not_found/2
```

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Phoenix you have installed? Check for `@version` in `deps/phoenix/mix.exs`.

Comment: @version "1.3.0"

Comment: Was this file created with `mix phx.new`? Can you post the output of `mix phx.new --version`? That function was added after v1.3.0 and should not be there if phx.new is v1.3.0.

Comment: That was it thank you :) I started off with dev phoenix but then switched to  1.3.0. Fixed by copying `status_message_from_template` from phoenix repo to my local.